# Unable to checkout log4j repository

Tags: svn, log4j, tortoisesvn

I'm using tortoiseSVN to checkout the log4j v1.2 source from - http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4j/trunk

But I keep getting this error:

> Error: OPTIONS of '': Could not
>   Error: resolve hostname `svn.apache.org': No such host is known.

The funny thing is that I can access 'svn.apache.org' from my browser but if I try to ping it from the command prompt, it says host not found.

Does any body else face this problem? Is there any other way to get the source for log4j v1.2?

Answer (score 0):

The [regular downloads](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html) include the source.

Comment: Thanks Thilo.

Boy...do i feel stupid now.

I would still need a way to be able to commit extensions though.